# Sitecore SXA search ordering with Solr

Tags: solr, sxa-search

I'm trying to understand how results are ordered when using a SXA `Search results` component without using a `Default sort order` option or a `Sort result` component. I need this for a site search, where many different items are listed and I can't use one standard ordering - at least I think I can't.

Let's say I get 3 results with the search word `Test`. If I go to Solr UI and search the `sitecore_sxa_web_index` under Query where `q` is `sxacontent_txm:'Test'` I get the same results with the same ordering as search results on site search.
If I change some content on those 3 result pages they sometimes change order and sometimes not. But when they change order on the site search they also change order in my Solr UI query. Therefore I assume that this is the query SXA search uses.

But I just can't figure out how this order is materializing. The `__boost` field has `0.0` for all 3 pages. The `Test` word has the same number of occurrences in all pages. Time of creation or update of the item is out of order as well. As far as I can tell, we don't have any active boosting rules. At least I couldn't find any under the used scope and the path `/sitecore/system/Settings/Rules/Indexing and Search`.

So I assume the ordering is coming from indexing. Has anyone some helpful information?

Thanks

Comment: Did you check the score field in Solr admin? You can add it to 'fl' and see what are the values. I think by default if no sorting is specified it sorts by score.

Comment: @YassineAlahyane Interesting. I didn't know about that. So if I add score to fl I can see the scores. Turns out two of the values are equal and the other is bit higher. How can I determine the score value?

Comment: Nevermind. I found it. Just checked debugQuery in Solr Admin UI

Comment: Solr Relevance Score is determined based on multiple factors. Here's a link explaining some of them. In simple terms Solr determines the most relevant results based on your search keywords amongst other things : https://help.sap.com/docs/SAP_SUCCESSFACTORS_RECRUITING/8477193265ea4172a1dda118505ca631/4f698829534d4787ab31b70b86d89702.html